# Observed Integration Shortcut, is it ok, and why?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

In an insurance problem involving integration I have:

"Losses, X $\sim Exp(\frac{1}{10})$. For each loss, the claim payment Y = to the amount of the loss in excess of a deductible d > 0" Find the variance of Y

Th solution proposes doing a piecewise approach, which makes sense to me up until the part with the last equivalency.

$Y=0$ when $X\leq d$  so $E[Y]=\int_0^d 0\cdot(.1e^{-.1x})dx+\int_d^{\infty } (x-d)\cdot(.1e^{-.1x})dx=0+\int_0^{\infty } x(.1e^{-.1(x+d)})dx$

Specifically, I don't understand why I can take the "d" out of the lower limit and then add it into the exponent of "e". Is this a common integration shortcut?

Comment: This is a common enough manipulation that I find thinking through the substitution overkill. Intuitively, you have shifted the limits by d, so you can integrate the shifted function. Imagine what you would do to evaluate this integral. You would integrate the function and then plug in the limits, and then take one away from the other. Plugging "d" into "x-d" and into "x" gives the same as plugging in "0" into "x" and "x+d" respectively.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the substitution $y=x-d$ so that $x=y+d$ and $dy=dx$. Also when $x=d, y=0$ and when $x\to \infty, y\to\infty$ so we have: 
$E[Y]=\int_0^d 0\cdot(.1e^{-.1x})dx+\int_d^{\infty } (x-d)\cdot(.1e^{-.1x})dx=0+\int_0^{\infty } y(.1e^{-.1(y+d)})dy$ 
Since $y$ above is a dummy parameter, it can be replaced by $x$ again.